# Altium - Daisy-chaining repeated schematic sheets

Tags: schematics, altium

Is there a more elegant way to do the following?

[image: altium screenshot]

Essentially I am trying to daisy-chain multiple "LED" devices, each with a data-in and data-out port. So do1 will be connected to di2, do2 -> di3... etc.

The way I have it works okay, but I'm wondering if there's a less manual way to connect them. Also, the way I did it gives "multiple names per net" errors. Is there a way you're supposed to connect signals from different buses without generating this error?

Thanks!

EDIT:

It seems like the [bus joiner](http://wiki.altium.com/display/ADOH/Schematic+Bus) components in the FPGA_Generic library can do what I need, but they don't work with non-FPGA projects.

I can't find any functionality like this for non-FPGA projects.

Answer (score 4):

I had a very similar problem. I found one simpler solution, maybe not entirely elegant, but it works.[image]

Comment: Rather than just an image this answer would be more useful if you explained how to achieve that end result.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the "right" way to do this is to instantiate the LED sheet 20 times, and route one to the next explicitly. This may *seem* more messy, but it explicitly defines a relationship that you're trying to trick the schematic compiler into building.